# What is the best boolean label for a prompt on a Report... "Display" "Show" or "Print"?

Tags: terminology, reports, prompt

Is there a universal standard for prompts that will be on a report?

For example if the user had to make a decision if they want to have the account numbers to show up on a report should it say:

Option 1: **Display Account Numbers**
Option 2: **Show Account Numbers**
Option 3: **Print Account Numbers**

Comment: Alternatively, you could say "Include account numbers" since the account numbers will be *included as part of* the report.

Answer (score 3):

**Show** seems easiest, as its common opposite is **Hide**; both are common words.

(where I've worked in the past with UX writers, we've been encouraged to use 'show / hide')

Display has other meanings, as in a 'display'.

Print is the *format* of the overall report (as in paper output; 'a printout'), regardless of the content that's shown or hidden. Print is also an action, but it sounds like your case is a configuration choice *before printing.*